# 8th wall web app setup child compilation failed

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, 8thwall-xr, 8thwall-web

I am new to 8th wall. I have cloned 8th wall web from [git](https://github.com/8thwall/web) and executed below steps properly

```
# cd <directory_where_you_saved_sample_project_files>
# cd serve
# npm install
# cd ..
# ./serve/bin/serve -d <sample_project_location>
```

but on execution of last step which is for ex.

```
./serve/bin/serve -n -d gettingstarted/xraframe/ -p 7777
```

I am getting below errors

> Failed to compile.
>
> Error: Child compilation failed:   Entry module not found: Error:
> Can't resolve
> 'C:\8thWall_Project\web\serve\bin\gettingstarted\xraframe"
> \index.html' in 'C:\8thWall_Project\web\serve':   Error: Can't resolve
> 'C:\8thWall_Project\web\serve\bin\gettingstarted\xraframe"
> \index.html' in 'C:\8thWall_Project\web\serve'
>
> - compiler.js:79 childCompiler.runAsChild
>   [serve]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:79:16
> - Compiler.js:306 compile
>   [serve]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:306:11
> - Compiler.js:631 hooks.afterCompile.callAsync.err
>   [serve]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:631:15
> - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
>   [serve]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
> - Compiler.js:628 compilation.seal.err
>   [serve]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:628:31
> - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
>   [serve]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20
> - Compilation.js:1325 hooks.optimizeAssets.callAsync.err
>   [serve]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1325:35

Any idea or pointers what is missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but bat file don't want to be opened by path. Just go to the serve\bin directory and launch bat from here, like that:

[image]

7777 is unnecessary. problem was, that it can't find path to your xraframe
project, as you are in another directory, so you have to go tow directories up in ypur path for xraframe

Comment: the best of the best doesn't knows why, then who knows?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you're attempting this on a Windows computer. The serve process for Windows is slightly different than on macOS.

Instead of the normal serve script, use the serve.bat executable.

```
serve\bin\serve.bat -n -d gettingstarted\xraframe -p 7777
```

https://docs.8thwall.com/web/#locally-from-windows

Comment: no I have tried this command before also but still the same issue